# How to get string between two specific symbols

Tags: c#, string, parsing, decoding

I have a string like This: `***T1***2DAR***R1***`. I want to get this three(T1,2DAR,R1) value in three different Strings. How to decode this strings between a specific symbol like *** from a single string in VS 2015?

Comment: string input = "***T1***2DAR***R1***";string[] output = string.Split(new char[] {'*'}, SplitStringOption.RemoveEmptyEntries);  I know somebody is going to suggest rexex which isn't needed in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the [String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) class :

```
var values = "***T1***2DAR***R1***".Split(new string[] { "***" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

### Edit :

This will return you a string array, you can access each value with the indexer :

```
string s1 = values[0]; // Will give you "T1"
string s2 = values[1]; // Will give you "2DAR"
string s3 = values[2]; // Will give you "R1"
```

Comment: And how I will get this three value in three different string? Please give the full code because I am a beginner in C#.

Answer (score 3):

This is where [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) comes in handy:

```
string[] items = "***T1***2DAR***R1***".Split(new string[] { "***" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

The code above returns an array containing `"T1"`, `"2DAR"` and `"R1"`.

The first argument indicates the separator(s), here `"***"`, and the second ensures that empty strings between separators wouldn't be returned. Without it, an empty string would be returned at the beginning (before the initial `***`) and at the end of your input (after the trailing `***`).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I think this is the code I was looking for. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Split` method like this:

```
string str = "***T1***2DAR***R1***";

var result = str.Split(new []{"*"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will give you an array of the individual strings.